# Logging in multithreeaded Application

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a trading application(million of data at a time) in java which is extensively multi threaded. The application is logging messages in a log file. Currently,the performance of this Logging is quite low and is taking lot of CPU time.

I want to re implement it.I googled and found `LinkedBlockingQueue` as an option.Can't use `arrayBlockingQueue` because of its fixed size.

Also,frameworks like log4j also sounds good option as they are thread safe.But I doubt if log4j is a good option performance wise for multi threaded application.

What could be the best Data Structure/framework that I should choose for doing logging in my multi threaded application?

Comment: Use a proven logging framework: it will be more efficient than whatever you could design in a reasonable amount of time...

Answer (score 5):

Try log4j 2 instead of reinventing the wheel...
http://www.grobmeier.de/log4j-2-performance-close-to-insane-20072013.html

Comment: See also http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html

Answer (score 3):

For high performance logging, I use [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) (mostly because I wrote it) It can support 100K - 1M text messages per second in a GC less way.  You can make it thread safe by wrapping it with a lock.  It is not as simple to use as other loggers as it is lower level, but it is the fastest that I know of.

If you use binary logging it can support over 10M messages/event per second.  I am working on a Java Chronicle 2.0 which is 3x faster.

Unbounded queue are usually a bad thing.  If a bound queue is not an option for your, most likely, you have a design issue.  If you really need an unbounded, Java Chronicle is likely to be you only option as no other library truly supports this in a performant way.  Log4j 2.0 uses a bounded ring buffer.

Comment: Hi Peter, do you have an example where text messages can be written using chronicle? Every example I can find is for writing binary data.

Comment: @CaptainHastings IndexedChronicleTest.testParseLines() and TestManyUpdatesMain. Have a look at ByteStringAppender.

Comment: @CaptainHastings It could do with a Logger like interface

Comment: Hi Peter, I see that you have started assimilating chronicle into the slf4j logging interface. Do you have a logger for multi-threaded writers?

Comment: @CaptainHastings Chronicle supports concurrent writers across processes. i.e. more than one process can write/read a chronicle.  However, we need to make money some day so the slf4j/logback/log4j appender will come with a subscription fee, most likely node count based.

Comment: Of course, most of us are happy to pay for quality software. I will keep an eye on your google forum for the details. Cheers.

Comment: Are any stats available for a comparison of Chronicle vs other logging frameworks?

Comment: @JiteshVassa the main difference is that Chronicle Queue is designed for a) low latency, b) zero GC, c) read in real time. Other loggers are not designed for this so it depends on your test as to how they behave.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd try [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) first.  This is just a facade, but you can use [log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) as the implementation.  *If* that's slow, it'll make it really easy to try JUL and other logging frameworks after that.  It's just a configuration and classpath change.

*If* every logger you try is slow, you might want to look into http://zeromq.org/.  But I think a logger should be fine.  I don't usually hear people complain about how their logging framework is slowing down their app unless they're printing out an excessive amount of debug statements.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't even think about going with log4j.** Please. Go for **logback**

> Logback is intended as a successor to the popular log4j project, picking up where log4j leaves off. Logback's architecture is sufficiently generic so as to apply under different circumstances. At present  time, logback is divided into three modules, logback-core, logback-classic and logback-access.

Logback has the appender you have already out-of-the-box. Is called **AsyncAppender**

> AsyncAppender logs ILoggingEvents asynchronously. It acts solely as an event dispatcher and must therefore reference another appender in order to do anything useful.
>
> LOSSY BY DEFAULT IF 80% FULL AsyncAppender buffers events in a BlockingQueue. A worker thread created by AsyncAppender takes events from the head of the queue, and dispatches them to the single appender attached to AsyncAppender. Note that by default, AsyncAppender will drop events of level TRACE, DEBUG and INFO if its queue is 80% full. This strategy has an amazingly favorable effect on performance at the cost of event loss.